# Got confused in conversion of UNICODE chars to UTF-8 Multibyte chars

Tags: unicode

I have to load one "dll" file in my application which is located in the path includes "UNICODE " characters. When I got the path in wchar_t* and pass it to LoadLibrary() works as expected.

But I am in another way
1. Converting array of wide char to UTF-8 multibyte array.
2. Converting again UTF-8 multibyte array to wide char array.
3. Now using the converted wide char array as path of library. LoadLibrary() is failing and GetLastError() is giving 216 ( Module not found error ).

I tried above steps thinking that input to the 1st will be output of 2nd step, But its not... :-(

Here is the code details about what I am trying to do...

```
wchar_t* path = L".\\..\\libs\\여성해방운동\\mylib.dll";

//STEP 1:
int creq = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,path,-1,NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
char* cpath = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*creq);
memset(cpath,0,creq);
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,0,path,-1,cpath,creq,NULL,NULL);

//STEP:2
int wreq = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,cpath,-1,NULL,0);
wchar_t* wpath = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*wreq);
memset(wpath,0,sizeof(wchar_t)*wreq);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,cpath,-1,wpath,wreq);

//STEP:3
if( LoadLibrary(wpath) == NULL )
    printf("Loading failed %d \n",GetLastError());
else
    printf("Loading is success \n");
```

I tried using cpath ( output of STEP 1 ) for loading the library using "LoadLibraryA" API, But it is also failed.

In my application I have to convert wide char array to multibyte array and reverse it back in another API. So please help me if anybody knows about this.

thanks.

Comment: see utf8everywhere.org, also boost::nowide which is the easiest way to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 1, you converted using CP_UTF8. So in step 2, you also need to call `MultiByteToWideChar()` with CP_UTF8.

I'd expect `LoadLibraryA(cpath, ...)` to fail, since it assumes cpath is in CP_ACP - whichever system code page your computer happens to be set to.